# Open a specific view when opening the App through a Notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, swiftui

I am able to open a specific view (ToDoView) when I use categories with actions for my notification.
But what I would like to achieve is that a specific view gets also opened when I click on the notification itself. 
Maybe this is super simple to solve, but I couldn't find out yet using SwiftUI.

By the way: This code only works if the app still runs in the background, otherwise i land at ContentView, which is also not optimal.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    return true
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == "open" {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ToDoView"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

**NotificationManager.swift**

```
    func scheduleNotifications() -> Void {
    for notification in notifications {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = notification.title


        var dateComponents = DateComponents()

        dateComponents.hour = 18
        dateComponents.minute = 10
        dateComponents.weekday = notification.weekday

        let open = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "open", title: "Notizen öffnen", options: .foreground)
        let cancel = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "cancel", title: "Schließen", options: .destructive)
        let categories = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "action", actions: [open,cancel], intentIdentifiers: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([categories])
        content.categoryIdentifier = "action"
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notification.id, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            print("Benachrichtigung mit folgender ID eingerichtet: \(notification.id)")
        }
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
.....
                  .onAppear {
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("ToDoView"), object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
                    self.showToDo = true
                } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the way: This code only works if the app still runs in the
>   background,

Instead of `.onAppear` in `ContentView` use subscription to publisher, like below

1) Declare publisher

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let todoPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("ToDoView"))
    ...
```

2) Add subscriber (in the place you added `.onAppear` and instead of it)

```
.onReceive(todoPublisher) { notification in
   self.showToDo = true
}
```

this will work as long as `ContentView` exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this leads to the exact same behaviour as my code from above does: ToDoView only gets opened while the App runs in the background, but when it was terminated it brings me to ContentView. Maybe this is what you meant with "this will work as long as ContentView exists"? But then I don't understand the advantage you want to provide compared to my code.

Comment: @Kuhlemann, the callback `userNotificationCenter(_ :didReceive...` must be called when application is launching on tapped notification action, so your `TodoView` notification should be posted. If it is not handled then it rather poster *before* ContentView is constructed. Thus you have to check if window is present delay posting notification if not.

Comment: @Asperi I am in the same situation. The didReceive method does not fire and the application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions has the launchOptions as nil.