# How to navigate to some view from apns click in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In swift 5 and UIKit on clicking apns I have been pushing to the desired view controller by fetching the top view controller and push the desired view controller over top view controller.

But in SwiftUI I am not able to do that. How can I navigate from apns in SwiftUI.

**I don't have to set desired controller as window root controller. I want to push the desired controller over the top view controller. I just want to push to a controller from apns click.**

I am getting apns click in this delegate method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a specific view when opening the App through a Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306123/open-a-specific-view-when-opening-the-app-through-a-notification)

Comment: @ Mohand Jumah No this is not I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own method in SceneDelegate. Create SceneDelegate object set its window rootViewController as follows.

```
extension SceneDelegate{

func loginViewController() {

 let loginView = LoginView()

 let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? 
 SceneDelegate
 sceneDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: 
 loginView)

 }
}
```

And call method like this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

//Call method here 
let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate
sceneDelegate?.loginViewController()

}
```